# Laravel: how to update records values coming as arrow

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I need to update records coming as array from a form.

```
    $a = $request->id;
    $b = $request->val;
```

Now I need to update the records

```
   Details::find($b)->update(['detail'=>$a]);
```

The script above obviously does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in more than one way, try this :

```
$details = Details::find($request->input($id));
$details->val = $request->input('val');
$details->save();
```

Or you can use this if the inputs has the same name as the model fields:

```
$details = Details::findOrFail($request->input($id));
$details->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Hi, I get following errror:Method update does not exist.

Comment: i have updated the answer, please check that `$details = Details::findOrFail($request->input($id));` retrieving the row you need

Answer (score 0):

You can update in the following ways. Assuming `detail` is your field name to update.

```
$id = $request->id;
$val = $request->val;

$detail = Details::findOrFail($id);
$detail->detail = $val;
$detail->save();
```

For the below to work. You need to set the `$fillable` propery in the model

```
// In Detail model
protected $fillable = ['detail'];

// Controller

Details::where('id', $id)->update([
    'detail' => $val
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = $request->id;
$b = $request->val;

$detail = Detail::where('id', $a)->first();
$detail->update(['detail' => $b]);
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with the answer so others will find it easier to understand.